# Recover funds from opbnb (Different proxy address)

Tags: safe-core

For context, I have Safe deployed on mainnet but trying to recover funds sent to the same address in opbnb. I went through the support page https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover case 1.

Is it possible to recover funds on networks like opbnb (chain id 204) which has different proxy address (0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC) than mainnet (0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, as a proxy contract has been deployed at this address (0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2) on opbnb too. You will have some issues using the UI when interacting with this safe, as it will detect it was not deployed by an "official" proxy factory; you will be able to interact with it by using the [CLI](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-cli) though.

Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Comment: Thanks Louis! Do you know if it's possible to facilitate sending non-ETH gas token / native token via the CLI?

Comment: Yes it is possible by using the `send_custom <address> <value-wei> <data-hex-str>` command; you will need to prepare the data that will be used by the token contract to transfer your tokens, and send it as `<data-hex-str>`.